# Save and Load dynamically generated checkedlistbox items

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I'm pretty new to VB, so bear with me.  On form load, a list of values is pulled from a database, and the values are used to generate a list of checkedlistbox items.

A user will select which checkboxes they want, and then click save, at which point the checked items are stored to a system.collections.arraylist type user setting.

I am able to save the values of the checkboxes to the user settings, but I'm trying to load the saved settings the next time the application is opened, but I'm unsure how to do this.  The only way I've been able to do it only gets the checked items, which isn't what I want.

Here's what I'm using to save the items:

```
Dim list As New ArrayList
        For i As Integer = 0 To CheckedListBox1.Items.Count - 1
            list.Add(CheckedListBox1.Items(i))
            i = i + 1
        Next
        My.Settings.selectedlistbox = list
        My.Settings.Save()
```

And this is what I've currently got to load the settings, which isn't working at all:

```
Dim counter As Integer
        counter = 0

        While counter <= My.Settings.selectedlistbox.Count - 1
            CheckedListBox1.SetItemChecked(counter, list(counter))
            counter = counter + 1
        End While
```

On a related note, I'm calling the above code prior to the code where the database connection is opened, so I'm thinking this may be a problem too, since I think the checkboxes won't be able to be accessed until they're actually in the application.  I tried placing the code after where the checkedlistbox is loaded, but that didn't work either.

Comment: That is VB.NET not VB6.  The checkedListbox does not contain checkboxes (oddly), just strings rendered as such.  It looks like you are saving all the items (instead of iterating CheckedItems), so when you load from Settings, you are checking them all (if that is what `isn't working at all` means).  Save the checkeditems and then realod from that - you should check if it exists in the list first if it can ever grow or shrink

Comment: is there an index associated with the checkeditems when I save them?  Because in order to know which boxes are checked when I load the form the next time, I need to either match the text or have an index of some sort...I previously had it written to where it was storing checked items, but I didn't see how it would know which ones were checked the next time it opened, especially if the list had grown.  I don't know if I'm making any sense..

Comment: there is a CheckedIndicies, but that does assume the list order will not change and the list will not shrink or grow.  It would be better to either save the Text of those checked OR a "key" to identify an item so that word order or spelling changes dont break your thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that `My.Settings.Useropts` is a StringCollection, to skip the ArrayList:

```
' CLEAR OUT OLD SELECTIONS so they do not accumulate
My.Settings.Useropts.Clear

' save items checked
For i As Integer = 0 To CheckedListBox1.CheckedIitems.Count - 1
    My.Settings.Useropts.Add(CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems(i))
Next
My.Settings.Save()
```

Or iterate the checkedindicies collection:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To CheckedListBox1.CheckedIndicies.Count - 1
    My.Settings.Useropts.Add(CheckedListBox1.Items(CheckedIndicies(i))
Next
My.Settings.Save()


' reload from settings

Dim ndx As Integer
For Each s as string in My.Settings.Useropts
   ndx = CheckedListBox1.Items.indexOf(s)     ' find this string in the list

   ' if NDX is -1 then the item does not exist;
   If ndx <> -1 then                          
      ' set the check for the related INDEX, if found:
      CheckedListBox1.SetItemChecked(ndx, True)
   Else
      CheckedListBox1.SetItemChecked(ndx, False)  
   End If
Next
```

If there arent default items in the collection you may need to initialize it on FormLoad.  The text for the CheckedList box cant change or items wont be found.

Since the Items collection can store Objects, you could devise a Class of {Name, Key} where key uniquely identifies each item, which Name might change as needed.  Store the Keys, then find them in the CLB to set that Item's checkstate as above

---

- Fixed typo in `SetItemChecked(n,` --> `SetItemChecked(ndx,
- Added warning about clearing old settings, annotated the restore loop